# Вызов функции через адрес поля класса

Tags: c++, указатели

Могу ли я определить указатель на функцию как поле в классе, записать в нее адрес функции (зная сигнатуру метода) и обращаться к данному полю как к функции?

К примеру так:

```
typedef void(*someSuperExtractedFunction(int,const char* const*));

class SomeFunctor
{
private:
    someSuperExtractedFunction* someAddress;
public:
    SomeFunctor()
    {
        someAddress = (someSuperExtractedFunction*)GetAdressOf("some_method");
        someAddress(0, nullptr);
    }
}
```

Comment: В вопросе содержится терминологическая каша. Указатель объявлен как указатель на обычную функцию. Он не может указывать на метод класса.

Comment: @AnT: Прошу прощения, не заметил что не дописал: `указатель на функцию как поле в классе`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, можете. Вот пример:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class My {
        void (*f)(int);
    public:
        My(void (*f)(int)): f(f) {}
        void doIt(int i) {
            f(i);
            }
    };

void g(int i) {
    cout << i << endl;
    }

int main() {
    My m(g);
    m.doIt(5);
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо, просто приходилось при каждом вызове функций, обращаться к списку который содержал указатели на функции, и каждый раз в методах объявлять локальные переменные.

Comment: Можно класс сделать шаблонным и вызвать функцию с любым аргументом

Answer (score 0):

Некое дополнение к первому ответу.  Можно вызвать функции с любым количеством аргументов любого типа

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <class... T>
class My {
        void (*f)(T...args);
    public:
        My(void (*f)(T...args)): f(f) {}
        void doIt(T...i) {
            f(i...);
            }
    };

void g(int i) {
    cout << i << endl;
    }
void g1(const string s) {
    cout << s.back() << endl;
}
void mg(int i, const string s) {
    cout << i << '\t' << s;
}

int main()
{ 
    My<int> m(g);
    My<string>  ms(g1);
    m.doIt(5);
    ms.doIt("abc");
    My<int, string> mis(mg);
    mis.doIt(20, "efg");
    return 0;
}
```

И впринципе можно делать так, чтоб вызвались функции и с возвращающим типом